# Erro ao criar projeto Xamarin cross plataform no Visual Studio. "O projeto requer um SDK da Plataforma (UAP, version=10.0.10.586.0)"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xaml, xamarin-forms

Ao tentar criar um projeto *Cross PlatForm App* com o template *Master Detail*
Eu recebo este erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O SDK que ele afirma estar ausente está instalado. Já o reinstalei várias vezes.

Quando eu tento criar um projeto *Cross PlatForm App* com o template *Black App (Xaml)* eu recebo este erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu acredito que os dois problemas sejam o mesmo, apenas exibido de uma forma diferente devido o template. Alguém tem alguma ideia?

Estou quase desistindo de usar Xamarin.Forms. Está dando absurdamente muitos problemas, mesmo no Xamarin nativo, os paus de referências fazem você perder um tempo absurdo!

Comment: Vai desenvolver para `UWP (win10)`? Caso não deseje pode desabilitar. É necessário `Windows 10` atualizado para desenvolver `UWP`. Tive um problema parecido, porém, para desenvolver especificamente para `win10´ tive que desinstalar e instalar novamente o `SDK`.

Comment: Vou sim, estou desenvolvendo um app multiplataforma. Precisa rodar no windows 10 mobile. 
Eu atualizei meu windows e ainda nada. 
: \ 

Acho que vou reportar pra microsoft

Comment: No link de ajuda da microsoft ta cheio de gente com o mesmo problema e sem resposta. 

Aff

Answer (score 1):

Sei que parece óbvio, mas existem alguns passos que são necessários para desenvolver para UWP:

- O Windows 10 deve estar atualizado (preferencialmente para a versão de Aniversário);
- Os Kits de Desenvolvimento do Windows 10 devem estar instalados;
- O modo Desenvolvedor deve estar habilitado.

---

**Passo 1**: Verificar Kits de Desenvolvimento (Programas e Recursos):

[image: Windows Software Development Kit - Windows 10.0.10586.212]

---

**Passo 2**: Verificar Modo de Desenvolvedor (Configurações > Para Desenvolvedores):

Para ativar ou saber se está ativado o modo de desenvolvedor, basta clicar no Menu Windows, depois clicar em Configurações e ir para a aba **Para Desenvolvedores**. A terceira opção (Modo Desenvolvedor) deve estar selecionada.

---

**Passo 3**: Instalar as Ferramentas de Desenvolvimento UWP (Visual Studio > Alterar > Modificar > Windows and Web Development > Universal Windows App Development Kit):

Caso não encontre instalados os kits de desenvolvimentos para UWP, basta buscar o Visual Studio em **Programas e Recursos** e clicar na opção **Alterar**. Depois basta selecionar a opção **Universal Windows App Development Tools** em Windows and Web Development e instalar as features.

[image: Universal Windows App - Ferramentas de Desenvolvimento]

---

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Esses passos todos que você postou eu fiz amigo, exceto a parte do modo desenvolvedor. Realmente não me lembro se ativei ou se após atualização eu desativei. 
Vou testar assim que chegar em casa e já posto aqui, obrigado.